# I want to add image on Visualforce PDF but i cant change its size

Tags: apex, visualforce, pdf

```
     <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Before Trial Image</th>
        <th>After Trial Image- 1ST Week</th>
        <th>After Trial Image- 2nd Week</th>
        <th>After Trial Image- 3nd Week</th>
    </tr>
   <apex:repeat value="{!drawingOilTrialMonitoring}" var="trial4" rendered="{!drawingOilTrialMonitoring.size>0}">
        <tr style="height: 200px;">
            <td id="rich1">
                <apex:outputField styleClass="customImage" value="{!trial4.Before_Trial_Image__c}" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;" />
            </td>
            <!-- Add the other columns here -->
        </tr>
    </apex:repeat>
</table>
```

anyone has any idea how can i achieve it

Answer (score 1):

`apex:outputField` has some extra layers between the field and the style, which is causing problems.

Try something like:

```
<style>
div.squareImage {
  display: inline-block;
}
div.squareImage img {
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}
</style>
```

Then:

```
<div class="squareImage">
  <apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!trial4.Before_Trial_Image__c}" />
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can read the field contents to extract the image fragment, then apply a width and height to that directly.